# How to upload multipart file (.CSV) in mirth connect

Tags: javascript, java, mirth

I am facing one issue in mirth connect. I am not able to upload CSV file as a multipart in mirth connect. I have created one channel where I created HTTP Sender and HTTP Listener and I am trying to send CSV file.

I am calling REST API where I need to send csv file as a parameters.

***My tried*** : I have tried to send csv file as a base64 but still it not worked.

Can anyone suggest any solution. I will really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: The forum threads at https://forums.mirthproject.io/search?q=send+multipart&searchJSON=%7B%22keywords%22%3A%22send+multipart%22%7D should be helpful.